# What is the difference between fiducial cosmology and non-fiducial cosmology?

Tags: cosmology, terminology

When conducting research to constrain the cosmological model, astrophysicisists often mention two types of cosmology: the 'fiducial' cosmology, and a cosmology incorporating some parameters (for example, the mass density parameter, $\Omega_m$, or $\sigma_8$).

From what I have read, it seems that the fiducial cosmology is using data under the assumption that the universe behaves exactly as we expect, almost like a 'perfect' universe. Whereas non-fiducial includes parameters that change things slightly.

Can someone please definitively outline the difference between these?

Comment: *"Fiducial"* just means standard, as in a primary model from which you make comparisons.  For example, I'd have a *fiducial* cosmology with certain parameters for $\Lambda$, $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_r$, $H_0$, etc and then I would compare varying $\Omega_m$ against the *fiducial model*.  It doesn't necessarily even mean an *accepted* cosmology, it's just a standard point of reference (usually in the context of a particular study).

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix Could you write this as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*moved from comments*

"Fiducial" just means standard, as in a primary model from which you make comparisons. For example, I'd have a fiducial cosmology with certain parameters for $\Lambda$, $\Omega_m$, $\Omega_r$, $H_0$, etc and then I would compare varying $\Omega_m$ against the fiducial model. It doesn't necessarily even mean an accepted cosmology, it's just a standard point of reference (usually in the context of a particular study)